# How to count unique names (First Name Col A and Last Name Col B) with additional criteria in other columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

Sheet 1 contains data entry from a user form.  See data below.

```
 A              B               D              I
First Name      Last Name       Date           Type
Jane              Doe           1/15/15        Fall
Jane              Doe           1/24/15        Behavior
Jane              Doe           2/21/15        Fall
Angel             Wings         1/10/15        Fall
```

Sheet 2 calculates the data from sheet 1 and tracks and trends the information

1. Count the number of unique names based on First and Last Name.  I figured out the Array formula for this one which is:

> =SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF('Event Tracker'!A5:A1502&'Event
>   Tracker'!B5:B1502<>"",MATCH('Event Tracker'!A5:A1502&"@"&'Event
>   Tracker'!B5:B1502,'Event Tracker'!A5:A1502&"@"&'Event
>   Tracker'!B5:B1502,0)),ROW('Event Tracker'!A5:A1502)-ROW(A5)+1)>0,1))

Here is where I really need help - I have tried every variation I can think of.

2.Count the number of unique patients `(Col. A + Col B)` with an event occurring between a specified date based on date in col. `D (>=1/1/15 and <=1/31/15)?`

3. How many unique patient names `(Col A + Col B) had a Fall (Col I)?`
4. How many unique patient names `(Col A + Col B) had a Fall (Col I) between >=1/1/15 and <=1/31/15` based on the date in column D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add additional conditions at the start of the `FREQUENCY` function, e.g. for how many different patients had a fall, use this:

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF('Event Tracker'!I5:I1502="Fall",IF('Event Tracker'!A5:A1502&'Event Tracker'!B5:B1502<>"",MATCH('Event Tracker'!A5:A1502&"@"&'Event Tracker'!B5:B1502,'Event Tracker'!A5:A1502&"@"&'Event Tracker'!B5:B1502,0))),ROW('Event Tracker'!A5:A1502)-ROW(A5)+1)>0,1))`

To add extra conditions you can just keep adding IFs in the same place......but don't forget to add the appropriate parentheses.

For between two dates the syntax is as follows:

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF('Event Tracker'!D5:D1502>="1/1/15"+0,IF('Event Tracker'!D5:D1502<="1/31/15"+0,IF('Event Tracker'!A5:A1502&'Event Tracker'!B5:B1502<>"",MATCH('Event Tracker'!A5:A1502&"@"&'Event Tracker'!B5:B1502,'Event Tracker'!A5:A1502&"@"&'Event Tracker'!B5:B1502,0)))),ROW('Event Tracker'!A5:A1502)-ROW(A5)+1)>0,1))`

Comment: This worked great for the fall but I still cant figure out how to get the number of unique patients during the month based on date of event occurring in Column D.  I tried to add this to the formula but it is not working.
    =SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF('Event Tracker'!D5:D1500,">=1/01/15",IF('Event Tracker'!D5:D1500,"<=1/31/15",IF('Event Tracker'!A5:A1500&'Event Tracker'!B5:B1500<>"",MATCH('Event Tracker'!A5:A1500&"@"&'Event Tracker'!B5:B1500,'Event Tracker'!A5:A1500&"@"&'Event Tracker'!B5:B1500,0)))),ROW('Event Tracker'!A5:A1500)-ROW(A5)+1)>0,1))

Comment: The criteria syntax for the dates isn't correct, I added a version for that to my answer (and also fixed my original formula because I omitted `="fall"`)

Comment: Thank you so much.  This worked perfectly.  I have finally finished the spreadsheet.  Only took me 5 weeks.  Thanks to everyone who assisted throughout the process.  I have learned so much from each of you.